# Request Header in Success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In an angular service I am making a get request with `$http.get('some/url/')`. I need to check the content-disposition for what the filename should be on a success. I'm not sure if there's a way to access headers so for now I'm using then. Is there a way to get headers in the success function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is there a way to get headers in the success function?**

As seen in [**AngularJs $http Documentation, second paragraph**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) *verbatim*

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: Was just about to say exactly that in a comment. OP clearly can not have bothered to look at the documentation before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$http.get('/some/Url').then(function(successResponse){
    console.log(successResponse); // this will print out the response object and you can access headers, config, data, etc.

}, function(failureResponse){
    console.log(successResponse);
});
```